# Javascript Canvas Attach image to other image

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am making a 2d multiplayer sword game using Node JS and Socket io.
I have the backend working but in the front end I cant get the sword to be attached on the player.
I want it to be like
[Sword is attached to player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RYDW.png)

But the problem is when i move mouse the sword changes and goes outside of the player.
[Sword is not attached to player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgmH3.png). So If you are wondering how my game works its basically the Smiley(player) always is pointing at the mouse (yes it may be upside down) and you can move player with arrow keys and use the sword to kill other players.

Here is my code that draws the player and sword.

```
function drawImageLookat(img, x, y, lookx, looky){
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  // set scale and origin
   ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(looky - y, lookx - x)); // set angle
   ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width / 2, -img.height / 2); // draw image
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default not needed if you use setTransform for other rendering operations
}

const drawPlayer = (player) => {
    const img = new Image()
    const img2 = new Image()

img.src = "./assets/images/player.png"
img2.src = "./assets/images/sword.png"
img.onload = () => {
drawImageLookat(img, player.x, player.y, player.lookx, player.looky)
drawImageLookat(img2, player.x+50, player.y, player.lookx, player.looky)
}

  };

  socket.on('state', (gameState) => {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0, 1200, 700)
    for (let player in gameState.players) {
      drawPlayer(gameState.players[player])
    }
  })
```

Basically this "state" is emitted 60 times a second with the gamestate. In the gamestate we have players object which contains stuff like LookX(Mouse X position),LookY(Mouse Y position), and X and Y of player. This code below is in server side.

```
const gameState = {
  players: {}
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('newPlayer', () => {
    gameState.players[socket.id] = {
      x: 250,
      y: 250,
      lookx: 0,
      looky: 0,
      width: 25,
      height: 25
    }
  })
//More stuff below here which is skipped
setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit('state', gameState);
}, 1000 / 60);
```

Also in client side, here is how I am getting mouse position

```
  //mouse stuf
  var pos = 0;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      pos = getMousePos(e)
  })
  
  function getMousePos(evt) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
      };
    }

//send 2 server
setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('mouseAngle', pos);
    socket.emit('playerMovement', playerMovement);
  }, 1000 / 60);
```

So basically All I want is that when I spin the mouse, the Player should always be pointing at the mouse and the Sword is attached to the side of the Player and spins with it....
Here is my full code if you need it...

```
//SERVER.JS
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

const gameState = {
  players: {}
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('newPlayer', () => {
    gameState.players[socket.id] = {
      x: 250,
      y: 250,
      lookx: 0,
      looky: 0,
      width: 25,
      height: 25
    }
  })

  socket.on('playerMovement', (playerMovement) => {
    const player = gameState.players[socket.id]
    const canvasWidth = 1200
    const canvasHeight = 700
    
    if (playerMovement.left && player.x > 0) {
      player.x -= 4
    }
    if (playerMovement.right && player.x < canvasWidth - player.width) {
    player.x += 4
  }
    
    if (playerMovement.up && player.y > 0) {
      player.y -= 4
    }
    if (playerMovement.down && player.y < canvasHeight - player.height) {
      player.y += 4
    }
  })

  socket.on("mouseAngle", (pos) => {
    const player = gameState.players[socket.id]
    player.lookx = pos.x;
    player.looky = pos.y;
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    delete gameState.players[socket.id]
  })
})

setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit('state', gameState);
}, 1000 / 60);




http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```
//Client/Index.html
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

const gameState = {
  players: {}
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('newPlayer', () => {
    gameState.players[socket.id] = {
      x: 250,
      y: 250,
      lookx: 0,
      looky: 0,
      width: 25,
      height: 25
    }
  })

  socket.on('playerMovement', (playerMovement) => {
    const player = gameState.players[socket.id]
    const canvasWidth = 1200
    const canvasHeight = 700
    
    if (playerMovement.left && player.x > 0) {
      player.x -= 4
    }
    if (playerMovement.right && player.x < canvasWidth - player.width) {
    player.x += 4
  }
    
    if (playerMovement.up && player.y > 0) {
      player.y -= 4
    }
    if (playerMovement.down && player.y < canvasHeight - player.height) {
      player.y += 4
    }
  })

  socket.on("mouseAngle", (pos) => {
    const player = gameState.players[socket.id]
    player.lookx = pos.x;
    player.looky = pos.y;
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    delete gameState.players[socket.id]
  })
})

setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit('state', gameState);
}, 1000 / 60);




http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```
//Client/Assets/Js/script.js
var socket = io();

var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

document.getElementById("game").width =1200;
document.getElementById("game").height = 700;

socket.emit('newPlayer');
//mouse stuff
function drawImageLookat(img, x, y, lookx, looky){
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  // set scale and origin
   ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(looky - y, lookx - x)); // set angle
   ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width / 2, -img.height / 2); // draw image
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default not needed if you use setTransform for other rendering operations
}

const drawPlayer = (player) => {
    const img = new Image()
    const img2 = new Image()

img.src = "./assets/images/player.png"
img2.src = "./assets/images/sword.png"
img.onload = () => {
drawImageLookat(img, player.x, player.y, player.lookx, player.looky)
drawImageLookat(img2, player.x+50, player.y, player.lookx, player.looky)
}

  };

  socket.on('state', (gameState) => {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0, 1200, 700)
    for (let player in gameState.players) {
      drawPlayer(gameState.players[player])
    }
  })
```

```
//Client/assets/js/Controller.js
//v1
var canvas = document.getElementById("game")


const playerMovement = {
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
  };
  const keyDownHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 68) {
        playerMovement.right = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 65) {
        playerMovement.left = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 87) {
        playerMovement.up = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 83) {

        playerMovement.down = true;
      }
  };
  const keyUpHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 68) {
      playerMovement.right = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 65) {
      playerMovement.left = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 87) {
      playerMovement.up = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 83) {
      playerMovement.down = false;
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler, false);

  //mouse stuf
  var pos = 0;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      pos = getMousePos(e)
  })
  
  function getMousePos(evt) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
      };
    }

//send 2 server
setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('mouseAngle', pos);
    socket.emit('playerMovement', playerMovement);
  }, 1000 / 60);
```

If you could help me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways this can be done. The standard method is to use a second transform and multiply it with the current context transform.

### 2D Matrix multiplication

The 2d API has two functions to enter a matrix  to change the current transform.

1. [`ctx.setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) Replaces the current transform with a new one
2. [`ctx.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform) Multiplies the current transformation with the new one setting he current transform to the resulting matrix.

This lets you attach image elements in a hierarchical transformation structure. (Tree like structure)

[`ctx.setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) is used to set the root transform and you use [`ctx.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform) to attach a child that inherits the previous transform as well has getting the secondary transform.

Say you have an image that you transform as you do with

```
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  
   ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(looky - y, lookx - x));
   ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);
```

The origin is at the center of the image

To attach another image say for example  the second image is centered on the bottom right corner of the existing image, and will rotate (scale, translate, skew, mirror, etc) with the existing image.

Just create a second transform that is relative to the current transform (previous image) and use [`ctx.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform) to do the matrix multiplication, then render the second image

```
   ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, img.height / 2);  // bottom right of prev image
   ctx.drawImage(img2, -img2.width / 2, -img2.height / 2);
```

### Save and restore the transform.

If you need to get the parent transform you will need to save and restore the 2D API state

```
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  
   ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(looky - y, lookx - x));
   ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);
   ctx.save();

   // draw second image
   ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, img.height / 2); 
   ctx.drawImage(img2, -img2.width / 2, -img2.height / 2);

   ctx.restore();  // get the parent transform

   // draw 3rd image at top right
   ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, -img.height / 2); 
   ctx.drawImage(img3, -img3.width / 2, -img3.height / 2);
```

The is ok for simple rendering but can be slow or inconvenient for more complex rendering.

### [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix)

Rather than use the built in transforms you can use `DOMMatrix` as it provides functions to do all the standard matrix math.

For example the previous 3 images can be done as

```
   const ang = Math.atan2(looky - y, lookx - x);
   const ax = Math.cos(ang);
   const ay = Math.sin(ang);
   const parentMatrix = [ax, ay, -ay, ax, x, y];
   const child1Matrix = new DOMMatrix([1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, img.height / 2]);
   const child2Matrix = new DOMMatrix([1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, -img.height / 2]);


   // draw first image with root transform
   ctx.setTransform(...parentMatrix);  
   ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

   // draw second image at bottom right
   const mat1 = new DOMMatrix(...parentMatrix);
   matrix.multiplySelf(child1Matrix);
   ctx.setTransform(mat1.a, mat1.b, mat1.c, mat1.d, mat1.e, mat1.f);  
   ctx.drawImage(img1,-img1.width / 2, -img1.height / 2);

   // draw third image at top right
   const mat2 = new DOMMatrix(...parentMatrix);
   matrix.multiplySelf(child2Matrix);
   ctx.setTransform(mat2.a, mat2.b, mat2.c, mat2.d, mat2.e, mat2.f);  
   ctx.drawImage(img2,-img2.width / 2, -img2.height / 2);
```

Comment: @CoderGautamYT Sorry I just noticed an error in the answer examples, the second and third `drawImage` calls in the first few examples used the wrong image size to position the images. I have updated answer to fix the error

Comment: How do I get the x and y of the sword? for collison detection

Comment: @CoderGautamYT Sword center you multiply the second transform origin Eg last two  of `ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, img.width / 2, img.height / 2)` by the inverse transform of the parent (root) transform. Easiest with `DOMMatrix`  Answer's last snippet, at bottom add,  `parentMatrix.invertSelf(); const pos = parentMatrix.transformPoint(new DOMPoint(img.width / 2, -img.height / 2));` the new `Point` ` holds the canvas x, y `pos` of center if sword .. continues next comment

Comment: ... To get coord  of point on second img, invert second transform and transform a point on second image, from same snippet, use second matrix. `mat2.invertSelf();const pos = mat2.transformPoint(new Point(-img2.width / 2, -img2.height / 2)` will give canvas pos of top left of second image

Comment: I am not using DOMMatrix, how to do with just normal canvas. Thanks for your time... Here is my repl... https://repl.it/@CoderGautamYT/FunChat-1#.replit

Comment: @CoderGautamYT 2D canvas does not provide that functionality, You either use `DOMMatrix` or write your own matrix object, in which case you will need to implement at minimum, matrix multiply matrix, invert matrix, and matrix multiply point

Comment: Ok I will try DOMMatrix

Comment: I get an error `script.js:31 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'DOMMatrix': Failed to parse '-0.7071067811865475'.`. Here is my current function Iam using https://pastebin.com/nBdZCUGW . If u want my full code look inside my repl

Comment: @CoderGautamYT see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix/DOMMatrix and more detailed spec https://drafts.fxtf.org/geometry/#dom-dommatrixreadonly-dommatrixreadonly